# YouTube Api for channel list

Tags: android, youtube

I am newer in youtube api,I need help for implementing youtube api in android. I have find one youtube api for getting all channel list on associated username [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername={USERNAME}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername=%7BUSERNAME%7D&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D). I have created 3 channels in my youtube account but above api is not getting response.

This is response for above api with valid username and api key

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/ewwRz0VbTYpp2EGbOkvZ5M_1mbo\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": []
}
```

Comment: Have you enable **YouTube Data API** in API Console?

Comment: use default youtube api provided by google developer console

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/

Comment: @ Lawrance: yes

Comment: @siddhesh: I need no of channels and video id associated with that user{username}

Answer (score -1):

Use it like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=channel_id&key=your_key
```

You can try your API request here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it

Request:

```
HTTP GET: GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id={CHANNEL_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
Response (with id=UCt7iVnJwjBsof8IPLJHCTgQ):

{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/WNxXCvycTyqTjTn9sLJ5toVjBRY\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/jijTuA_iWn2Kv9aRnqeAWNAcQ6I\"",
   "id": "UCt7iVnJwjBsof8IPLJHCTgQ",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "796662",
    "commentCount": "20",
    "subscriberCount": "257",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "126"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

You can pass in a comma-separated list of Channel IDs for the id parameter. Because I only passed in one id, the first object of the items array will have the values you need. Get the object for the subscriberCount and videoCount values in the statistics dictionary for the data you want.

Comment: How to get channel id from youtube api or how to get all channels from my account with details.